# display.newImage() vs display.newImageRect() in corona

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk, displayobject

What is the difference between `display.newImage()` and `display.newImageRect()`?

Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of [`display.newImage()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html) mentions specifically:

> **NOTE:** [`display.newImageRect()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html) should be used instead to load images
>   when dynamic content scaling is enabled.

And similarly, on [`display.newImageRect()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html)

> `dispaly.newImageRect()` automatically substitutes higher-resolution
>   assets on higher-resolution devices. The actual image chosen will
>   depend on the current content scale determined by Corona, which is the
>   ratio between the current screen and the base content dimensions
>   defined in **`config.lua`**.
>
> Based on this scale, Corona uses the
>   `imageSuffix` table (also defined in config.lua), which lists the
>   suffixes for the same family of images, to find the best match from
>   the image choices available.